# unable to stack 5 circles on each other in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

What i am trying to achieve is:
[image]
what i have achieved and stuck on is:
[image]
i am using inkwell widget inside a container

Code:

```
Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: InkWell(
                  child: new Container(
                    width: 120.0,
                    height: 120.0,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),//I used some padding without fixed width and height
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,// You can use like this way or like the below line
                      //                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    child: new Text("", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    // You can add a Icon instead of text also, like below.
                    //child: new Icon(Icons.arrow_forward, size: 50.0, color: Colors.black38)),
                  ),
```

please help.

Comment: Please do not vandalise your post. We aim for questions and their answers to have lasting utility for others with the same subjects problem to solve. Removing the images hinders that goal and invalidates the work the answers have put into providing a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

You can notice, that actually this is one element with different colors, it is going through the circle with angle of 360/5 degrees

- you can use

```
Path.combine(
          PathOperation.reverseDifference,
```

[image]

```
    import 'dart:math' as math;

    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    const double degrees2Radians = math.pi / 180.0;
    void main() => runApp(MyApp());

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: Scaffold(
            body: SafeArea(
              child: MyHomePage(),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }

    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      int _currentSliderValue = 2;

      List<Color> colors = [
        Colors.blue,
        Colors.red,
        Colors.yellow,
        Colors.green,
        Colors.purple,
        Colors.orange,
      ];
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: CustomPaint(
                  painter: MyPainter(
                    colors: colors.take(_currentSliderValue).toList(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Slider(
              value: _currentSliderValue.toDouble(),
              min: 2,
              max: 6,
              label: _currentSliderValue.toString(),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  _currentSliderValue = value.round();
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    }

    class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
      const MyPainter({
        @required this.colors,
      }) : super();

      final List<Color> colors;

      @override
      void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
        var paths = <Color, Path>{};
        colors.asMap().forEach((index, color) {
          var degree = 360 / colors.length * (index + 0.5);
          var radian = degree * degrees2Radians;

          var path = _onePath(radian, size);

          if (index > 0) {
            path = Path.combine(
              PathOperation.difference,
              path,
              paths[colors[index - 1]],
            );
          }
          if (index == colors.length - 1) {
            paths[colors[0]] = Path.combine(
              PathOperation.reverseDifference,
              path,
              paths[colors[0]],
            );
          }
          paths[color] = path;
        });

        for (final color in colors) {
          var path = paths[color];

          final fillPaint = Paint()
            ..color = color
            ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
          canvas.drawPath(path, fillPaint);

          final strokePaint = Paint()
            ..color = Color(0xFFC4C4C4)
            ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
            ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.butt
            ..strokeWidth = 10;

          canvas.drawPath(path, strokePaint);
        }
      }

      Path _onePath(double radian, Size size) {
        var circleSize = 150.0;
        var center = size.center(Offset.zero);
        var maxSize = math.min(size.height, size.width) / 4;
        var sin = math.sin(radian);
        var cos = math.cos(radian);

        var rect = Rect.fromLTWH(
          center.dx - circleSize / 2 + (sin * maxSize),
          center.dy - circleSize / 2 + (cos * maxSize),
          circleSize,
          circleSize,
        );
        return Path()
          ..addRRect(
            RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
              rect,
              Radius.circular(
                rect.height / 2,
              ),
            ),
          )
          ..close();
      }

      @override
      bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Kherel, your anwser is great. :))

Answer (score 3):

maybe you can use `Alignment(x, y)` and `ClipPath`:

```
class Demo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.grey,
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment(-0.15, 0.3),
                child: buildCircle(Colors.purpleAccent),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment(0.2, 0.3),
                child: buildCircle(Colors.blue),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment(0.3, -0.1),
                child: buildCircle(Colors.red),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment(0.0, -0.3),
                child: buildCircle(Colors.yellow),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment(-0.3, -0.1),
                child: ClipPath(
                  // Clip the green circle.
                  clipper: Clipper(),
                  child: buildCircle(Colors.green),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                child: buildCircle(Colors.white, width: 30, height: 30),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Container buildCircle(
    Color color, {
    double width = 50,
    double height = 50,
  }) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      width: width,
      height: height,
      child: InkWell(
        child: new Container(
          width: width,
          height: height,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          //I used some padding without fixed width and height
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            // You can use like this way or like the below line
            //                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
            color: color,
          ),
          child: new Text("",
              style: new TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 30.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          // You can add a Icon instead of text also, like below.
          //child: new Icon(Icons.arrow_forward, size: 50.0, color: Colors.black38)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Clipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    return Path.combine(
      PathOperation.difference,
      Path()
        ..addOval(
          Rect.fromCircle(
            center: size.center(Offset(0, 0)),
            radius: 25.0,
          ),
        ),
      Path()
        ..addOval(
          Rect.fromCircle(
            center: size.center(Offset(10, 30)),
            radius: 25.0,
          ),
        ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yea, and then use Media.query(context).size.width/height insted of numbers in x, y. This is so the app also works on otherscreen-aspect-ratios.

Comment: thats what i have already achieved and stuck on, did you notice how every circle should overlap the next one?  @JackShen

Comment: You can do this by customizing the view, not the stack.@Lilly

Comment: i have updated my answer using `ClipPath`, hope to help u.@Lilly

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FractionalTranslation`:

```dart
Center(
  child: Container(
    height: 400,
    child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        FractionalTranslation(
          translation: Offset(-0.22, -0.1),
          child: CircleContainer(color: Colors.green),
        ),
        FractionalTranslation(
          translation: Offset(-0.15, 0.2),
          child: CircleContainer(color: Colors.purple),
        ),
        FractionalTranslation(
          translation: Offset(0.15, 0.2),
          child: CircleContainer(color: Colors.blue),
        ),
        FractionalTranslation(
          translation: Offset(0.22, -0.1),
          child: CircleContainer(color: Colors.red),
        ),
        FractionalTranslation(
          translation: Offset(0, -0.25),
          child: CircleContainer(color: Colors.yellow),
        ),
        CircleContainer(color: Colors.white, size: 130),
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

```dart
Widget CircleContainer({Color color = Colors.white, double size = 160}) {
  return Container(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: InkWell(
      child: new Container(
        width: size,
        height: size,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
          20.0), //I used some padding without fixed width and height
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape
          .circle, // You can use like this way or like the below line
          //                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          color: color,
        ),
        child: new Text("",
                        style: new TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 30.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
// You can add a Icon instead of text also, like below.
//child: new Icon(Icons.arrow_forward, size: 50.0, color: Colors.black38)),
      )));
}
```

Result:

[image: res]

Comment: thats what i have already achieved and stuck on, did you notice how every circle should overlap the next one?